# iOS In-App Purchase: Managing auto-renewing subscriptions

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscription, auto-renewing

I'm currently working on incorporating in-app purchases into an iOS application.  The primary offering will be auto-renewing-subscription based. My question concerns subscription management.

It is not possible (AFAIK) to manage AR subscriptions in the sandbox environment.  Apple's documentation [here on expiration and renewal](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH7-SW3) and [here on managing subscriptions](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202039) indicate that the user may disable auto-renewal and then renew it at a later date.  In the event of a disable action taken from the device AppStore, does the auto-renew option remain available in perpetuity -- e.g., in the IAP programming guide example there is a lapse of about two months before the user renews.  What about a year?  I assume that since the record of the AR transaction persists indefinitely, so does the App Store capability to manage the subscription?  I also assume that a caveat here would be that the product offering was still available in the store.

Anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my experience as a user, I was subscribed to an auto-renewal app and then turned off renewals. My subscription expired Jan. 27, 2015 (5 months ago) and I deleted the app from my phone soon after. After deleting the app, the renewal settings for it disappeared from my iTunes Store > Apple ID > Manage Subscriptions section. Today, to check your question, I just reinstalled the app and the renewal settings reappeared in Manage Subscriptions, including correct information about the expiration date and options to renew (resume) my subscription.